# Issue with utilizing both if statements at a time according to the situation

Tags: python, list, if-statement, nlp

There is a sentence from which I am trying to remove certain words. I don't know if I am using the if statement correct but one of the word in the words list is getting removed when I am testing it. Below is my code:

```
def remove_stopwords(sentence):
  stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", "of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves" ]

  sentence = sentence.lower()

  for word in stopwords:
    token= " " + word + " "
    token1= + word + " "

    if (token in sentence):
      sentence = sentence.replace(token, " ")
      sentence = sentence.replace("  ", " ")
      if (token1 in sentence):
        sentence = sentence.replace(token, " ")
        sentence = sentence.replace("  ", " ")
  
  return sentence
```

The sentence I am trying to test it on is:

```
remove_stopwords("I am about to go to the store and get any snack")
```

If you can observe there is a word "i" in stopwords list and in the test sentence which is at the beginning. The first condition I kept is the word which I am looking should like (space) + word + (space). 2nd condition should be like + word + (space).

In the test sentence, the first word "I" don't have space at the beginning and it should take the 2nd condition and shouldn't be present/omitted in the result. But it is not.

The result should be like "**go store get snack**" but I am getting "**i go store get snack**". Please help.

Both the conditions should be used here. Whenever the 1st condition situation comes up, it should execute 1st condition's code and whenever there is situation where it should use 2nd condition, it should use it and execute that code. I don't know if I used the if statements in this manner. Please help.

Comment: Currently you have nested `if` statements. Align them on the same level instead, so each can be evaluated independently from the other.

Comment: I just tried but it is throwing another error "TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'" while creating variable token1. token1= + word + " ".

Comment: That's because of the spurious + in `token1 = + word`.

Answer (score 0):

For your interest, here's another way to do it using split() which breaks a sentence at spaces. The strip() in the return just removes the space at the end which was added in.

```
def remove_stopwords(sentence):
    result = ''
    stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", "of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves" ]
    for word in sentence.split():
      if word.lower() not in stopwords:
          result += word + ' '
    return result.strip()
    
x = remove_stopwords("I am about to go to the store and get any snack")
print(x)
```